# How to push changes from one local branch to another local branch on Git?

Tags: git

I am working on a branch named say

```
abc
```

and I should be working on a different branch say

```
xyz
```

By mistake I did not see before the development that I was on a different branch, but now the work is done and i have to push my code from local branch 'abc' to another local branch 'xyz'.I'm not very much experienced with the Git, so kindly help me, that how do I push the code from branch abc to local branch 'xyz'? And do I need to commit the code on my local branch 'abc' before pushing the code into the local branch 'xyz'. How do I proceed?

I thought of creating a new local branch xyz by checking out from local branch abc, and before making the changes I wanted to commit the code in my local branch abc. This is what I have thought, I did not do anything as of now because I do not want this code to go missing.

Comment: Is abc a new branch you created and started committing work to? And those commits should instead be on top of xyz?

Comment: 'abc' is a branch whose parent branch is the main branch. No, 'xyz' is a new branch which I want to create and I want the same code as that in local branch 'abc'. But I have not committed the code changes in the local branch 'abc'.

Comment: Oh. Could you rename abc to xyz? `git branch -m xyz abc`?

Comment: *Branches* (more precisely, branch *names*) do not have parents. Commits have parents; each branch name selects exactly one commit, which we call the *tip* commit of that branch, and then the branch is that commit plus earlier commits—all of them, including commits that are also on other branches. (See Schwern's answer and the drawings.)

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on a branch named say abc and I should be working on a different branch say xyz .By mistake I did not see before the development that I was on a different branch, but now the work is done and i have to push my code from local branch 'abc' to another local branch 'xyz'.

From what I understand, you created a new branch (I'm going to assume from main) and made some commits. But you should have been committing to an existing branch called xyz.

Your repository looks something like this. A, B, and C are your new commits.

```
          A - B - C [abc]
         /
1 - 2 - 3 [main]
         \
          X - Y - Z [xyz]
```

What you want is this.

```
1 - 2 - 3 [main]
         \
          X - Y - Z [xyz]
                   \
                    A - B - C [abc]
```

Your abc commits will be built on top of xyz.

If that's is so, you can [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description) your abc commits on top of xyz.

```
# Rebase the commits in abc, excluding those in main, on top of xyz.
$ git rebase --onto xyz main abc
```